# "YouTube Movies" YouTube videos won't play in embedded player

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

When trying to play a "YouTube Movies" video (either purchased or "Free With Ads") in an embedded player, the player won't play the video, and instead shows the error: "Your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats available."

The error is followed by a link that says "Click here to visit our frequently asked questions about HTML5 video.", and clicking there goes to a page that says "You're awesome! That's right! Your browser is up-to-date, which means you can use YouTube's latest features. Enjoy!"

The embedded player WILL play the purchased video correctly if I'm running the page from my own computer, but will not play the video if the page is hosted on a website.

This is similar to another question from two years ago ([Licensed Content Doesn't Load in Embedded YouTube Player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41269675/licensed-content-doesnt-load-in-embedded-youtube-player)) which was never answered.

Normal YouTube videos work fine in the embedded player, but YouTube Movies ones do not. I've tried it with the purchased movies Frozen and Gravity, and with the "Free With Ads" movie The Secret of Nimh.

To reproduce, use the sample code here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

...and replace the video ID with one from a YouTube Movies movie (e.g. "Ja8TsLgOGfI" for Secret of Nimh). Open the webpage locally, and observe that the video plays correctly, then copy the webpage to a website and try to run it from there, and observe the error.

I expect this to play the same on a website as it does on my local machine, but on a website it will not play and gives me the error shown above instead.

Comment: I don't see why they would allow embedding purchased videos in other websites.

Comment: I would be OK with "it's not allowed" being the official answer, but I'm asking here to make sure it's not just something I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! I was hosting it on an http site, rather than https. When I moved it to an https site, the videos all started playing correctly! Hooray!